# regex to ignore special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Say, I have a text stored as:

```
var val1 = 'l-oreal';
```

I want to match `val1` such that, it reads `val1` and ignores hyphen (dash) in it.  I want a regex that ignores special characters in a text. Is that possible?

I don't want to remove special character from the text. I want to ignore it.

Comment: how about `[a-zA-z0-9]*`

Comment: could you give me the list of your special characters?

Comment: @Allan all special characters.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're asking? What would be the expected result of your regex on your val1 string? And what have you tried so far code-wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match against the regex `/[a-z]+/gi` and then join by a space or any other character:

```js
var testString = "any string l-orem";
var matcher = /[a-z]+/gi;
var matches = testString.match(matcher);
var result = matches.join('');
console.log(result);
```

This, of course, doesn't change your original string, and can be simply customized to your own needs.

Comment: what is matches.join(''); doing? Can you tell please?

Comment: @FarazDurrani -- Please read about [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). It returns an array of RegExp matches. I've simply joined those to create a string again.

Comment: i is ignore case I understand. What is g? and what is +?

Comment: @FarazDurrani -- you really need to understand RegExp basics. Please refer to a good tutorial. `+` is to match one or more occurences of previous token. `g` is to match globally in the source string.

Comment: Is it possible that regex must include certain characters, for example lorem, and exclude all special character?

Answer (score 5):

You can either use `^` in order to select your special characters then replace it to an empty string `''`, as:

```
val1.replace(/([^a-zA-z0-9]+)/g, s0 => ''); // loreal
```

All except `a-zA-Z-0-9` will be removed.

---

Updated post for scenario when:

> The string must contain characters abc and ignore any special
>   characters

for this approach, you could make use of match to know if your string has any matches on your regex. If so, then you could use replace to switch special chars to empty string:

```
function strChecker(str) {
    var response;
    if(val1.match(/lorem/)) {
       response = val1.replace(/([^a-zA-z0-9]+)/g, s0 => '');
    }
    return response;
}

strChecker('ha-ha?lorem') // returns hahalorem
strChecker('ha-ha?loram') // return undefined
```

Comment: Is it possible that regex must include certain characters, for example lorem, and exclude all special character?

Comment: i didn't get it. would you like to change all special characters to 'lorem' as example?

Comment: Like.. a regex that must contain characters, lets say xyz, and ignore hyphen if string contains special characters.

Comment: like... one regex that has both. The string must contain characters abc and ignore any special characters

Comment: you can check if string contains your regex using `match`, i've edited my response to add it

Answer (score 4):

```js
var val1 = 'l-oreal';
var val2 = val1.replace(/\W/g,'');  // remove any non-alphanumerics

console.log(val1);   // still the same, not changed
console.log(val2);   // only alphanumerics
```

Comment: @guijob maybe that is what the OP wants. but thanks for the note

Comment: Is it possible that regex must include certain characters, for example lorem, and exclude all special character?

Comment: @FarazDurrani you can do that. just check `var val3='sometext lorem othertext';  var val4=val3.match(/lorem/g).join('');`

Comment: it will match lorem fine but it will not ignore hyphen would it?

Comment: @FarazDurrani you said you only wanted to match `lorem` so that is what it does.